# calling a function from a structure

Tags: c++, c, structure

i have the following code. I just want to know the meaning of the last line of the code.

```
typedef struct Details 
{
int D1; 
int D2;
} Sdetails;




typedef struct  Variable    
{
    int   Type; 
    Sdetails  i;
}Varialbl3;


typedef XAN_BOOL (*returnfunction)(variabl3* Data);


typedef struct _function
{
    returnfunction          fr;

}function1;


function1 *f1;
variabl3  v3;

f1->fr(&v3);
```

what does the last line f1->fr(&v3) indicates? I dont understand the concept.

Answer (score 4):

`f1` is a pointer to a struct. The struct has a member called `fr`, which is a pointer to a function. The function takes a pointer to `variabl3` and returns `XAN_BOOL`.

Thus, `f1->fr(&v3)` calls the function pointed to by `f1->fr`, supplying the address of `v3` as the sole argument, and ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 2):

It calls `fr` function.

`f1` is pointer to `function1` (which is struct):

```
typedef struct _function
{
    returnfunction          fr;
}function1;
```

---

`function1` has member - a pointer to function - named `fr`. The function, pointer by `fr` takes one argument - `variabl3`:

```
// pointer to function, taking one argument with type 
// `variabl3` and returns typedef struct _function
typedef XAN_BOOL (*returnfunction)(variabl3* Data);
```

---

So, `f1->fr(&v3)` calls `fr` and passes `v3` as parameter. The return value is `XAN_BOOL`, as described in the typedef.

---

By the way, if this is real code - this is **undefined behaviour** as `f1` is **uninitialized**.

Answer (score 1):

f1 is a pointer a kind of struct; that struct's only member is a pointer to a function. That last line calls the function held by the pointer in an instance of that struct, and passes the address of an instance of the `variable3` struct as the function's argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointer on a function : basically, you're calling an abstract function that can be set somewhere else.

You should have a real function somewhere like:

```
XAN_BOOL realFunction(variabl3* pxData) { return (pxData==0); }
```

Then you can do : `f1->fr = realFunction` : you make your function pointer point to the real function. Then, when you call f1->fr after, it will call realFunction.

This is widely used in a lot of design patterns : when you want to register callbacks, in listeners/triggers, when you want to implement object-oriented design in pure C, when you want to eract to UI (you attach a behaviour to a button, in GTK for example).

Hope this helps, if anything unclear, ask in comment and I'll edit.